# ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (5), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (12)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

this piece of code was working before, however, after creating a new environment , it stopped working for the line

```
plt.xticks(x, months, rotation=25,fontsize=8)
```

if i comment this line then no error, after putting this line error is thrown

```
ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (5), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (12).
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = df
dfsize = dataset[df.columns[0]].size
x = []
for i in range(dfsize):
    x.append(i)

dataset.shape
# dataset.dropna(inplace=True)
dataset.columns.values
var = ""
for i in range(dataset.shape[1]):  ## 1 is for column, dataset.shape[1] calculate length of col

    y = dataset[dataset.columns[i]].values
    y = y.astype(float)
    y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
    y.shape
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

    missingvalues = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', verbose=0)
    missingvalues = missingvalues.fit(y)
    y = missingvalues.transform(y[:, :])

    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

    labelencoder_x = LabelEncoder()
    x = labelencoder_x.fit_transform(x)

    from scipy.interpolate import *

    p1 = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    # from matplotlib.pyplot import *
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.figure()
    plt.xticks(x, months, rotation=25,fontsize=8)
    #print("-->"+dataset.columns[i])
    plt.suptitle(dataset.columns[i] + ' (xyz)', fontsize=10)
    plt.xlabel('month', fontsize=8)
    plt.ylabel('Age', fontsize=10)
    plt.plot(x, y, y, 'r-', linestyle='-', marker='o')
    plt.plot(x, np.polyval(p1, x), 'b-')
    y = y.round(decimals=2)
    for a, b in zip(x, y):
        plt.text(a, b, str(b), bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.9))

    plt.grid()
    # plt.pause(2)
    # plt.grid()

    var = var + "," + dataset.columns[i]
    plt.savefig(path3 + dataset.columns[i] + '_1.png')
    plt.close(path3 + dataset.columns[i] + '_1.png')
    plt.close('all')
```

Comment: Your error seems to indicate that you are using a different dataframe. And that `dataset[df.columns[0]].size` now is 5 while before it was 12.

Comment: yeah, i understand, but could not get why this dynamically working before now got changed.

Comment: Well, you're using a different dataframe.

Comment: i used same and different dataframes, as i tested  the same code multiple times, it was working, its that now i had to change my laptop so python version is the latest of 3.7, i assume somewhere this has caused the issue. Anyways, i corrected this issue.

Comment: Let me guess. You used matplotlib version 3.2.2 and today created a new environment with matplotlib 3.3.0. Something is broken in new version although I didn't find an exact bug report yet. I suggest to revert back to 3.2.2 until this is resolved.

Comment: Gregory Shimansky, your suggestion seems valid , i will try this but currently i have fixed the latest error reported here. Earlier i was having matplotlib version as 3.2.1 and now i am having 3.3.0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also stumbled across the error and found that making both your xtick_labels and xticks a list of equal length works. So in your case something like :

```
def month(num):
  # returns month name based on month number


num_elements = len(x)
X_Tick_List = []
X_Tick_Label_List=[]

for item in range (0,num_elements):
    X_Tick_List.append(x[item])
    X_Tick_Label_List.append(month(item+1))

plt.xticks(ticks=X_Tick_List,labels=X_Tick_LabeL_List, rotation=25,fontsize=8)
```

Comment: I try to solve this issue in python 3.7.3 (in Spyder 3.3.6 in Ubuntu), But I am plotting pandas boxplot. Is it possible to rethink a solution, as the above seems not applicable for my situation. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

I am using subplots and came across the same error. I've noticed that the error disappears if the axis being re-labelled (in my case the y-axis) shows all labels. If it does not, then the error you have flagged appears. I suggest increasing the chart height until all the y-axis labels are shown by default (See screenshots below).

Alternatively, I suggest using `ax.set_xticks(...)` to define the  `FixedLocator` tick positions and then `ax.set_xticklables(...)` to set the labels.

[Ever 2nd y-axis label drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2wTP.jpg)

[Every y-axis label drawn and over-written with custom labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36ldn.jpg)

Comment: This worked fine for me too. First, of course, the axis needs to be created.

Comment: Unfortunately this problem reccures in python 3.7.4 ( I use spyder 3.3.6 in Ubuntu) and your suggestion is not solving it. Could we perhaps rethink another solution? I have the exact issue of a code that had not problems a year ago and now throws this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an overnight upgrade to 3.4.3 under anaconda python's 3.9.7. (under OSX)
Does anyone have a solid solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

The questions seems to be a bit older but I just stumbled across a similar problem: the very same error occurred for me with the line
`ax.set(xticklabels=..., xticks=...)`
after an update to matplotlib version 3.2.2 which worked OK until then.

The `set` method of an axis seems to call other methods according to the order of the arguments of `set`. In older matplotlib versions, after unpacking the set-arguments there seems to have been some sort of ordering.

Rearranging the order of the parameter such that first the new number of xticks are set solved the problem for me:
`ax.set(xticks=..., xticklabels=...)`

Answer (score 0):

Happens when matplotlib failed to pack columns names in gist. Previously I had 5 columns and it was OK, next time I had 100+ columns and it caused an error.

Error in line:

`g.set_xticklabels(df['code'], rotation=15, fontdict={'fontsize': 16})`